# How to solve Error 13 ERR_BIND_SOCKET agora.io on premise recording SDK Record by API

Tags: java, agora.io

I tried the the command line to run the SDK on Ubuntu 18.04. It worked perfectly. I want integrate the sdk into a web project on Intellij IDEA So I could run the SDK by API Calls. But I got the following error :  [log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akRpD.png)

From the agora documentation it said that: [doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x3tp.png)

Could someone explain why this error occurs? Thank you

Comment: please share a code snippet of erroneous code as well

Comment: How are you instantiating the SDK with your web project?

Comment: i have this error any have the idea?? i believe at error with firewall with your pc

Answer (score 0):

i resolved the error, after generating the agora.node you must give permission 777 on the directory of the project is only that

Answer (score 0):

I successfully solved this issue. Go to the directory that you are recording to. There will be a file called `recording_sys.log`. At the end of this log file (last but 1 line actually) it said failed to execute a binary file. The path of the binary file is also mentioned. Just add execute permission (`chmod +x /path/to/binary`) for this binary file and the issue will resolve.

Edit: The name of this binary file is `AgoraCoreService`